# How do I edit material-ui package installed locally with npm

Tags: node.js, material-ui

Is it possible to edit an npm package after you npm install it locally? I have npm install-ed material-ui locally but I wanted to make a few edits like comment a line to see how it works but the changes don’t reflect on the UI/Chrome React extension. 
I have tried restarting the node server and restarting the browser. I have even tried ‘npm edit’. Do I need to rebuild the package after editing it? Not sure what I’m missing.

Comment: editing the file within your application's `node_modules` will do the trick. If it's not console.logging, that means the function isn't being hit. If you `npm install` after editing them, the changes will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

As cdbajorin pointed out, any edits you make in node_modules will show up. However, keep in mind that package A may depend upon v1.0 of package B, but your own project may depend directly on package B. To preserve the ability to have dependencies on different versions, the package B that package A depends upon will have it's own node_modules so it can sometimes be tricky to figure out where to edit.

That said, I would only recommend that you do that for debugging (which sounds like might be your only need). If you wanted to make a permanent change, a better way to do it would be to fork the original package and edit your fork. Forking is real easy on GitHub and 99% of the npm packages I've seen are on GitHub. You can then put a reference directly to your fork in package.json. So, if you were to run this:

```
npm install --save git+https://git@github.com/visionmedia/express.git
```

You'd get this in your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "git://github.com/visionmedia/express.git",
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can push your fork to npm under a different package name.

Best still would be to submit a pull request to the original package for any permanent upgrades you wish to make.